# Angular-Charts bar chart does not update when I change the data, series, labels

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm trying to create a drilldown bar chart based on this code:
https://shaynedcoder.wordpress.com/2016/10/14/angular-chart-drilldown/comment-page-1/#comment-10
I created an object with a primary chart, a list of drilldown charts and a temporary chart. The chart directive in the template is set to show the data, series, and labels of the primary chart. What this code does is that it switches the primary chart with a drilldown chart. I checked using chrome that the switch is happening, but somehow the chart is not changing whatsoever.

Here's the template:

And here's my controller

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ["chart.js"]).controller('ChartController',['$scope', function($scope){
 
  var colors = ['#A13030', '#E4882B', '#56932A', '#1D5F8A', '#317C73', '#6E5282']; // color code for all charts
   var options = { // common config of all charts
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
        }
    };
    var primaryDataModel = { //object definition (use as a template)
        header: "",
        labels: [],
        series:[],
        data: [],
        colors: colors,
        options: options,
    };
    var drilldownDataModel = { //object definition (use as a template)
        header: "",
        labels: [],
        series: [],
        data: [],
        colors: colors,
        options: options,
    };
    var chartModel = { // object definition (use as a template)
        uid: "",
        primary: null, //obj of primaryDataModel
        drilldown: null
    };
     var primaryData = { //object definition (use as a template)
        header: "Happiness Across Dubai",
        labels: ["Umm Al Rumool","Al Barsha","Wasel Center", "Tasjeel Al Qusais","Dubai Driving Center"],
        series:["Happy", "Neutral", "Unhappy"],
        data: [[33,22,44,11,42],
          [15,24,67,43,11],
          [42,11,67,90,42]],
        colors: colors,
        options: options,
    };
     var drilldownDataUmmAlRumool = { //object definition (use as a template)
        header: "Umm Al Rumool",
        labels: ["Male", "Female"],
        series: ["Happy", "Neutral", "Unhappy"],
        data: [[22,31],[52,21],[57,31]],
        colors: colors,
        options: options,
    };

     var drilldownDataAlBarsha = { //object definition (use as a template)
        header: "Al Barsha",
        labels: ["Male", "Female"],
        series: ["Happy", "Neutral", "Unhappy"],
        data: [[26,33],[22,61],[17,35]],
        colors: colors,
        options: options,
    };

     var drilldownDataWaselCenter = { //object definition (use as a template)
        header: "WaselCenter",
        labels: ["Male", "Female"],
        series: ["Happy", "Neutral", "Unhappy"],
        data: [[59,97],[53,51],[54,32]],
        colors: colors,
        options: options,
    };

     var drilldownDataTasjeelAlQusais = { //object definition (use as a template)
        header: "Tasjeel Al Qusais",
        labels: ["Male", "Female"],
        series: ["Happy", "Neutral", "Unhappy"],
        data: [[22,3],[56,12],[87,34]],
        colors: colors,
        options: options,
    };

     var drilldownDataDubaiDrivingCenter = { //object definition (use as a template)
        header: "Dubai Driving Center",
        labels: ["Male", "Female"],
        series: ["Happy", "Neutral", "Unhappy"],
        data: [[2,33],[12,71],[37,31]],
        colors: colors,
        options: options,
    };
    var chart1 = { // object definition (use as a template)
        uid: "barChart",
        primary: primaryData, //obj of primaryDataModel
        drilldown: [drilldownDataUmmAlRumool, drilldownDataAlBarsha, drilldownDataWaselCenter, drilldownDataTasjeelAlQusais, drilldownDataDubaiDrivingCenter],
        temp:null
 };
 $scope.charts = chart1;


 $scope.onClick = function(points, evt, barClicked){
  if (points.length!=0){
   if (barClicked){
    $scope.a="s";
    var setIndex = barClicked._index;;
    changeToDrilldown( setIndex); 
   }
  }

 }

 function changeToDrilldown(setIndex){
  if ($scope.charts.temp===null){ // check that this chart is not already in a drill down
     $scope.charts.temp = $scope.charts.primary;
     $scope.charts.primary = $scope.charts.drilldown[setIndex];


  }
 }
 $scope.backClick = function(evt){
  var chartId = evt.target.id;
    if ($scope.charts.temp!=null){
     $scope.charts.primary = $scope.charts.temp;
     $scope.charts.temp = null;
    }
   }
  
 }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="bower_components\angular\angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components\chart.js\dist\Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components\angular-chart.js\dist\angular-chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ChartController.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ChartController">
 <canvas class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="charts.primary.data" chart-labels="charts.primary.labels" chart-options="charts.primary.options" 
  chart-series="charts.primary.series" chart-click="onClick" ></canvas>

 </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap drilldown with `$timeout` to trigger digest cycle:

```
function changeToDrilldown(setIndex){
    if ($scope.charts.temp===null){     
     $timeout(function () {
         $scope.charts.temp = $scope.charts.primary;
         $scope.charts.primary = $scope.charts.drilldown[setIndex];
     }, 0);
  }
}
```

---

<kbd>[Demo in Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ivdCyq5YFOk4yT1l4tK3?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: I just have a question, why doesn't it update on its own? Isn't charts part of the scope model of the app?

Comment: @akeira99 `Chart.min.js` is a 3d party and works out of angular digest cycle. To trigger it we use timeout

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!